# RexExp (?=) structure

Tags: javascript, regex

consider you are searching for Cs that are appeared after a Bs.
Why following code returns -1 instead of 2:

```
console.log('abc'.search(/(?=b)c/));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [`(?=` is for lookahead, not lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

> `q(?=u)` matches a `q` that is followed by a `u`, without making the u part of the match.

---

And before you ask: [JavaScript regex does not support lookbehind](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript). In this simple case, however, you can use a workaround based on lookahead:

```
var index = 'abc'.search(/b(?=c)/);
if (index !== -1) index++;
console.log(index);
```

This works because you're looking for the position of `c` preceded by `b`, but this is logically the same as one greater than the position of `b` followed by `c`.

Before you get too excited, however: **you do not need regex for this. At all.**

```
var index = 'abc'.indexOf('bc');
if (index !== -1) index++;
console.log(index);
```